# PGN Viewer Usage

Tags: javascript, chess

I am developing a chess game, and I searched for a method to parse PGN chess files in javascript.

I found PGN Viewer Usage, here is the link:
http://chesstempo.com/pgn-usage.html

I did exactly the steps explained and added it to my code, but unfortunately, when trying to preview the code in chrome, an alert appears with this message:

pgn load failed:communication failure for file:/kasparov.pgn

the problem is that the code can not see the file (kasparov.pgn), this file exists in the same folder with my html file.

I tried to write the full path of the file but the same problem appeared.
can you tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Are running your test locally? with an adress like "file:///C:/Users/.." on your address bar? If so, maybe you should run the script on a localhost server. (See Xampp for more).

There are many scripts that don't execute properly on local files.

Comment: Yes I am testing locally, can you please tell me the steps to test on local server, as I am new to developing

Comment: It's a web enviroment that you could use to test easily your HTML/JS/CSS development.